# Improving string searching

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I have a table named “Articles” which contains an Article_body field which might contain more than 1000 characters for each record.
And i have a search web page to search these articles by inserting any string and retrieve all the articles that contains this string in their Article_body field .i am currently doing this using the .contain method as following:-

```
**public IQueryable<Question> searcharticles(string q)
    {
        return from a in entities1.articles
            where (a.article_body.Contains(q)  
 select u;}**
```

Currently the search is working fine, but i am afraid that when i will have thousands of articles this might not work efficiently, so i have the following two questions:-

1. is there a better way to do the search ?.
2. if i add a index on the article_body field will it speed up the search (i do not think so!!)?
   Thanks in advance for any help.
   BR

Comment: Have you considered something like [Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)?  It might be overkill, but it's very scalable, and high performance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) (assuming your database is SQL server)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have SQL Server

There are couple of way you can improve performance.

1. Create proper non-clustered index with covering column as well.

   ( Read about cover index)
2. Full Text Search of SQL Server but this require enterprise licence if you want to host online
3. Try Lucene Indexing

Comment: Full Text Search is available in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition with Advanced tools. So there is a free version with FTS and it can handle databases up to 10GB in size.